# mongodb replication in sharded machine

Tags: mongodb, replication, sharding

I have done Replication in one single machine with three different port(Say 27018[master],27019,27020). Also I have done Sharding in one single machine with two different port(Say 27021,27022).

Now I have to implement replication for the sharded machine port. I need to implement replication for 27021 and 27022. How can I do this? Please help me to resolve this issue.

Steps followed :

Part 1: Set up 3 port for replication

1. mongod --replSet rs0
2. mongod --port 27018 --dbpath F:\Data1 --replSet rs0
3. mongod --port 27020 --dbpath F:\Data2 --replSet rs0
4. mongo localhost:27017
5. rs.initiate()
6. rs.add("ComputerName:27018")
7. rs.add("ComputerName:27020")

Part 2: Now set up for sharding

8. mongod --configsvr --replSet configReplSet
9. mongod --port 27021 --dbpath F:\Data4 --replSet configReplSet
10. mongod --port 27025 --dbpath F:\Data5 --replSet configReplSet
11. mongo 127.0.0.1:27019
12. rs.initiate({_id:"configReplSet",configsvr:true,members:[{_id: 0,host: "127.0.0.1:27021"},{_id:1,host: "127.0.0.1:27025"}]})

When I run this code I am getting an error:

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "No host described in new configuration 1 for replica set configReplSet maps to this node",
    "code" : 93
}
```

So remaining steps I am not able to execute.  Any idea how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Can you add your tries?

Comment: @lovegupta I tried this link https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/convert-replica-set-to-replicated-shard-cluster/ But the issue I faced in              rs.initiate( {
   _id: "configReplSet",
   configsvr: true,
   members: [
      { _id: 0, host: "mongodb07.example.net:27019" },
      { _id: 1, host: "mongodb08.example.net:27019" },
      { _id: 2, host: "mongodb09.example.net:27019" }
   ]
} ) and  mongos --configdb configReplSet/mongodb07.example.net:27019,mongodb08.example.net:27019,mongodb09.example.net:27019 --chunkSize 1
The sharding environment is not able to set..

Comment: Please let me know if I need to provide my tries step wise step.

Comment: @Vinitha Yes, it would be useful if you could list the steps you've tried. Remember that you are encouraged to [edit] your question to improve it as much as possible.

Comment: @Vinitha can you just help me with the mongo version and your machine config. I am specifically looking for 32 bit/64 bit and koee interested in the storage engine you are using. I think i got the issue.

Comment: @lovegupta Mongo version is 3.2 and my machine is 64bit.

Comment: @Vinitha can you have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dn45G2yw20A . File used in this video can be downloaded from https://university.mongodb.com/static/MongoDB_2017_M101J_January/handouts/init_sharded_env__m101p_55315ad9d8ca39503877dfe8.8b6c8d37a891.bat . This example is from mongoDB university and takes three shards (each with three replicas) into consideration. I hope you are using WiredTiger storageEngine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got one method to achieve my requirement.
Steps as follows

### Config Server and its replication

- mongod --configsvr --dbpath F:\Data1\configdb\ --replSet rs2 --port 27017
- mongod --configsvr --dbpath F:\Data2\configdb\ --replSet rs2 --port 27018
- mongod --configsvr --dbpath F:\Data3\configdb\ --replSet rs2 --port 27019
- mongo *machineip:27017*
- config= {_id:"rs2", members :[{ _id:0, host:'10.18.0.225:27017'}, {_id:1, host:'10.18.0.225:27018'}, {_id:2, host:'10.18.0.225:27019'}]}
- rs.initiate (config)
- rs.status()

### Routing Server

- mongos -configdb machineip:27017 --port 27020

### Shard1 and its replication

- mongod --dbpath F:\Data4\db\ --shardsvr --replSet rs0 --port 27021
- mongod --dbpath F:\Data5\db\ --shardsvr --replSet rs0 --port 27022
- mongod --dbpath F:\Data6\db\ --shardsvr --replSet rs0 --port 27023

### Shard2 and its replication

- mongod --dbpath F:\Data7\db\ --shardsvr --replSet rs1 --port 27024
- mongod --dbpath F:\Data8\db\ --shardsvr --replSet rs1 --port 27025
- mongod --dbpath F:\Data9\db\ --shardsvr --replSet rs1 --port 27026

### Replication configuration for Shard1

- mongo machineip:27021
- config= {_id:"rs0", members :[{ _id:0, host:'machineip:27021'},{_id:1,host:'machineip:27022'},{_id:2,host:'machineip:27023'}]}
- rs.initiate(config)
- rs.status()

### Replication configuration for Shard2

- mongo machineip:27024
- config= {_id:"rs0", members :[{ _id:0, host:'machineip:27024''},{_id:1,host:'machineip:27025''},{_id:2,host:'machineip:27026''}]}
- rs.initiate(config)
- rs.status()

### Sharding Configuration in route server

- sh.status()
- sh.addShard ("rs0/machineip:27021")
- sh.addShard ("rs0/machineip:27024")
- sh.status()
- sh.enableSharding ("test")
- sh.shardCollection ("test.stud", {id: 1})
- sh.status()

Hope this will help :-)

Comment: did the comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43204999/mongodb-replication-in-sharded-machine#comment73578365_43204999 help?? Does it work only on wiredTiger? Tried many things but failed om mmapv1.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/ According to this documentation, while initiating replica set for config server, there should be a key "configsvr" : true. But this is not the case in your answer. Otherwise it will be deployed as a normal replica set.